# Recording audio in background service

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to record a few seconds of audio once the activity is sent to the background using the `moveTaskToBack(true);` method. I created a Service where the record starts and also set the time I want the audio to be recorded. The problem comes once it minimizes. It stops recording after 2 seconds more or less, and I need it to be recording for about a minute. I'm wondering if its really possible to record audio if the app is running in background.

My Service records like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fake.getFilename());
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();

            recorder.start();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recorder.stop();
                }
            }, 6000000);

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my activity calls the service and closes like this:

```
public void mecierro() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Panic.this, Record_service.class);
        Panic.this.startService(intent);  //starting the service

        start1 = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           }

           public void onFinish() {
            moveTaskToBack(true);  //"minimizing" the app
           }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: When your app goes to background, it can be easily killed by low memory monitor -- that's one if the reasons it can stop recording. I would try grabbing a wakelock -- you probably don't want the device to fall into sleep mode while you are recording anyway, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is one hundred percent possible to record audio in the background.
Use a service to launch the recorder.
Then the activity in which u start this service use the method 
    `startForeground()` instead of `startService()`
This is because your service gets killed before it can record further. Foreground services are less likely to be killed unless forced by user.